# Calculated balance of purchased lots

Tags: t-sql

I have a list of purchases by date.  EG:

ItemCode, Purchase Date, Purchase Qty

- XXX, 01 Jan 2012, 10
- XXX, 10 Jan 2012, 5

For the item I have a corresponding Sales transactions:

Item, Sales Date, Sales Qty

- XXX, 02 Jan 2012, -5
- XXX, 09 Jan 2012, -3
- XXX, 11 JAN 2012, -3

I am looking to get a SQL query (Without a cursor), to get the balance on each purchase order quantity.  I.e Run each purchase (First in first out) to 0. (For the purposes of aging inventory )

How can you join the Purchases to the Sales to get this balance remaining each purchased Inventory Lot?  Is this possible without a cursor?

Comment: what version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: What is the result you are looking for? If you could post the actual expected result records, it would make it a lot simpler to understand what you are looking for. Also, it is important to know which version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: @RichardVivian Would you post your final SQL code as you said? I have the same problem and am looking for a solid solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You `union` the two tables together, and run a running total on the resulting set.

```
   ;with cte as 
   (
       select itemcode, purchasedate as tdate, purchaseqty as qty from purchases
       union
       select itemcode, salesdate, salesqty from sales
   )
   select 
    t1.*,
    SUM(t2.qty)
   from cte t1
    left join cte t2 
        on t1.tdate>=t2.tdate
        and t1.item = t2.item
   group by t1.item, t1.pdate, t1.qty
```

To get the stock remaining at any particular time the same principal applies.

```
select p1.*, 
    case when (select SUM(abs(qty)) from sales) > SUM(p2.qty) then 0
    else SUM(p2.qty) - (select SUM(abs(qty)) from sales)  end as stockremaining         
    from purchases p1
    left join purchases p2 on p1.item = p2.item 
    and p2.purchasedate <= p1.purchasedate
group by p1.purchasedate, p1.item, p1.qty
```

gives

```
1   2012-01-01    10    0
1   2012-01-10     5    4
```

Comment: A running total will give me the stock on hand at any date, but not the stock remaining on a purchase batch.  I have been down this path of analysis with a running total, but it does not give the required result.

Comment: Thanks.  This put me on the correct track. Will post the final SQL when complete for reference